# Unable to get my smoke + fire Simulation to be of a realistic quality

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I am currently working on a client's freelance project but have hit a wall with the smoke+Fire simulation/Mantaflow. I have been looking at all the youtube videos, forum posts and the like to help get the client's desired result. I want realistic rocket combustion that does look fuzzy or pixelated.

I've tried to change up my materials, settings and render engine but they only seem to make subtle differences and I'm just finding myself running out of options. I can't recall everything I have tried as I have tried for an embarrassingly long time but with any suggestions, I will know If I have tried them before hopefully, that doesn't cause problems.

Here is my file: https://mega.nz/file/JKZm0bQa#BixcS2BvxOuazb4lbo7gMJYxtc7Vo7_Jmkc74ZUoUBw

For some reason it won't let me upload images so here is a link to them:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ0kc.jpg

Comment: did you watch Polyfjords fire/smoke simulation tutorial?

Comment: [Image uploading fails with "Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382854/295232) so you're not the only one with issues.

Comment: I did watch the Polyfjords fire/smoke simulation tutorial